# Can't see page in local lan

Tags: python, network-programming, cherrypy

I try to setup a simple webinterface with cherrypy & python.

The page is visible over `localhost:8080`. If I try a different computer on the same LAN and try to connect with it via `192.168.1.100:8080` it doesn't work however. Do I need to open some ports? I thought this would not be needed with linux.

OS: Ubuntu on both systems 
Tried Browsers Chrome & midori

Comment: @Malcom. I don't think I have any firewall installed on the serverside. It's a shrinked version of the default ubuntu. Is there a simple way to check?

Comment: Make sure to bind your server to `0.0.0.0:8080`, and not `localhost:8080`. Localhost means the loopback interface, which is only reachable locally, `0.0.0.0` means "all interfaces".

Comment: 0.0.0.0 works on the server side...

Comment: Hmm, 192.168.1.100:8080 doesn't work on the same computer that has this IP, curious

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to bind your server to `0.0.0.0:8080` instead of `localhost:8080`.

`localhost` always resolves to the loopback interface, which is only reachable from the same host.

`0.0.0.0` on the other hand means "all interfaces" (also known as `INADDR_ANY`).

For details read up about `INADDR_LOOPBACK` and `INADDR_ANY` in the [`ip(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ip.7.html) manpage.

Comment: That did the trick thanks. Adding the line `cherrypy.server.socket_host = '0.0.0.0'`